# How do I get Aptana Plugin for Eclipse to validate against CSS3, rather than CSS2?

Tags: css, eclipse-plugin, aptana

In my CSS files, I get these and similar error messages:

> The pseudo-element ::selection can't appear here in the context css2
>
> Value Error : background-color (http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/colors.html#propdef-background-color) RGBA(0,0,0,0.7) is not a background-color value

And similar errors for background-image. I keep reading that Aptana supports CSS3, but I can't find anything on how to make it use that for validation instead of CSS2. I've checked Preferences -> Aptana -> Validation -> CSS, I've made sure I'm using the Aptana editor, checked file associations, and I can't find any options for it. I just updated Aptana.

Here's my Aptana version:
Aptana Studio 3 Plugin 3.0.9.201202140953-7E777Q7HFGVBKBSEW7S_Iz0JktqM  com.aptana.feature.studio.feature.group

Here's my Eclipse version:
Version: Helios Service Release 1
Build id: 20100917-0705

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to change your CSS validation resources. You can find on the Aptana forums different posts of users that want to have a feauture. Please post a ticket at Aptana.